# Habilitar metodo POST en Laravel Folklore\GraphQL o habilitar metodo GET en react-apollo

Tags: laravel-5, reactjs, graphql

Estoy intentando conectar React con Folklore\GraphQL de Laravel.

En ReactJS tengo el siguiente código en `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

import { ApolloClient, ApolloProvider, createNetworkInterface } from 'react-apollo';
import Devices from './components/Devices.js'

const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
    uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphiql',
    opts: {
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        mode: 'no-cors',
    },
});
const client = new ApolloClient({ networkInterface });

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Devices />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Y en `Devices.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

class Devices extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return(
            <div>Hello</div>
        );
    }
}

const query = gql`
{
    devices {
        id_device,
        name,
        type,
    }
}
`;
export default graphql(query)(Devices);
```

Pero muestra el siguiente error:

> POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphiql 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Y si le agrego el `method:'GET'` en `opts` muestra el siguiente error:

> Unhandled (in react-apollo) Error: Network error: Failed to execute
>   'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.

¿Cómo puede agregar el metodo POST a Folklore\GraphQL? 
¿Cómo puede agregar el metodo GET a ApolloClient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EL error fue mío, porque yo puse la URL de l ainterface de GraphQL. La URL correcta es http://127.0.0.1:8000/**graphql**